Redis pubsub handling via cluster - processing only once
I am publishing the message in the AWS Elasticache cluster.
And there is a subscriber who is listening to the channel. However, the subscriber runs in JBoss cluster.
So if there are three servers in a cluster then there are three listeners and they all will process the message.
How to avoid this situation and only process messages once?
I created a cluster code to publish, you can assume clusterclient works well, as I have tested it.
public StatefulRedisClusterPubSubConnection<String, String> getClusterPubSubConnection() {
        clusterClient = this.establishConnection();
        //sample codecs can be used in future
        //final RedisCodec<String, byte[]> codec = RedisCodec.of(new StringCodec(), new ByteArrayCodec());
        //final RedisCodec<String, String> codec = RedisCodec.of(new StringCodec(), new StringCodec());
        //return clusterClient.connectPubSub(codec);

        return clusterClient.connectPubSub();

    }

publish code
`  public void publishToXXXChannel(CacheConstants cacheConstants, String key, String checkoutTimeInSeconds)  {
    String redisKey = this.getDelimiter().add(cacheConstants.getCacheName()).add(key).toString();
    StatefulRedisClusterPubSubConnection<String, String> connection=  connectToRedisCluster.getClusterPubSubConnection();
    RedisClusterPubSubCommands commands = connection.sync();
    commands.publish("EncounterCheckoutTimeChannel",redisKey );
    // The may be in seconds
    commands.expire(redisKey ,Long.parseLong(checkoutTimeInSeconds));

}`

subscriber code
  public void subscribeToXXXChannel StatefulRedisClusterPubSubConnection<String, String> connection = connectToRedisCluster.getClusterPubSubConnection(); connection.addListener(new XXXListener()); connection.sync().subscribe("XXXChannel"); }
I have created a custom listener, not posting the code here.
